# Rsync over SSH and passwordless key security

Tags: linux, ssh, security, rsync

I need to send files from a group of servers to a remote server. My plan was to use rsync over SSH as it meets my requirement of a secure connection and the ability to delete from source upon successful transfer. I can also restrict the firewall to only allow IP's that I trust on port 22.

If I setup a cron job to transfer these files using rsync over SSH, I'm assuming I would need to setup SSH keys to communicate. However, what is the security risk of storing public keys on a bunch of servers? Is it better to create individual keys per server? This account will only be used to transfer files.

Editing to expand on my network.

I have multiple servers hosted by 3rd party hosting company that all have public IP's. My home network has a static IP and servers sit behind a NAT'd router. So I'm not sure how I can pull data on the central server from the devices behind the NAT.

I could create a central server behind the NAT that collects everything and open up a port forward out. With a firewall that restricts port 22 and the static IP of the database server, I guess that would handle any possible security breaches.

Comment: If you can do the opposite. Put all the keys on the cental one and defend it! It's more easy to maintain update one server that a bunch of clients.  :)

Comment: I was thinking this too as it would work for all servers with a public IP. However, I'm not sure how it would work inside the LAN in my house with one static IP.

Comment: There's negligible risk in storing _public_ keys on a bunch of servers. They're public, and don't need to be kept secret. The risks are in storing _private_ keys on servers, or using public keys to grant access to servers.

Comment: Add the precise description of your network. Is the central server outside your network and all the clients with private ip behind a firewall? There's a way to access to the single client from the server (even via noip)?

Comment: I modified my question to explain my network Hastur.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do the opposite if you can.
2. Do a script on the central server with all the rsync actions, and run it **from that server**.
3. You will keep all the access keys on it. You can set on all client /bin/nologin as a shell to decrease the risks again.
4. If one of the client will fall, all the others will continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

I will add that when using rsync over ssh it is always a good idea to restrict which command can be run with a corresponding key: even if the private key is stolen on the central server only this command can be run on the group of others servers.

You can do this with the "command=custom_script" option in the "authorized_keys" file.

Just use the "rrsync" script as the "restricting command" it does a perfect job. (/usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync.gz on debian-like distrib)

More details here:

http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/01/14/restricting-ssh-access-to-rsync/

https://www.v13.gr/blog/?p=216